# recursive function that navigate a tree and returns a string

Tags: flutter, recursion, dart

I am stacked writing a recursive function that navigates a tree, search for something starting from the bottom, and returns a string.
This is what I am using now without success:

```
String parseAttachment(String filename, String bodyRaw) {
    var splitBoundary = '';

    var rx1 = RegExp(r'boundary="(.*)"');
    var match1 = rx1.firstMatch(bodyRaw);
    if (match1 != null) {
      splitBoundary = '--' + match1.group(1); // + '\r\n';
    }

    if (splitBoundary.isNotEmpty) {
      var stringSearch = RegExp('filename=("|)${_escape(filename)}("|)', caseSensitive: false);
      
      for (var childPart in childParts) {
        if (childPart.isNotEmpty) {
          return parseAttachment(filename, childPart);
        }

        if (childPart.isNotEmpty && childPart.indexOf(stringSearch) > -1) {
          var file64 = childPart.substring(childPart.indexOf(stringSearch)).trim();
          return file64.replaceAllMapped(stringSearch, (match) {
            return '';
          }).trim();
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The problem of this function that is somewhere in the tree the `if (splitBoundary.isNotEmpty)` statement is false and function always return null.

Comment: tree of what?, what is the structure of the tree?

Comment: an IMAP response